# Returning custom message in tastypie in obj_create method

Tags: python, tastypie

I am writing Rest API in tastypie and creating custom resource as follows

```
class Myresource(Resource):
      def obj_create(self, request, **kwargs):
          # logic when POST request is called
          # here if some error occurs while inserting data I want to add my custom error message and return it response. 
          return bundle
```

How can I return custom error message from obj_create message. right now I am handling exception but tastypie always return 201.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to override the wrap_view method in your resource as mentioned [here](https://gist.github.com/MacMaru/1116962) .

This is how its should work.

```
class YourResource(ModelResource):

def wrap_view(self, view):
    """
    Wraps views to return custom error codes instead of generic 500's
    """
    @csrf_exempt
    def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            callback = getattr(self, view)
            response = callback(request, *args, **kwargs)

            if request.is_ajax():
                patch_cache_control(response, no_cache=True)

            # response is a HttpResponse object, so follow Django's instructions
            # to change it to your needs before you return it.
            # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/
            return response
        except (BadRequest, ApiFieldError), e:
            return HttpBadRequest({'code': 666, 'message':e.args[0]})
        except ValidationError, e:
            # Or do some JSON wrapping around the standard 500
            return HttpBadRequest({'code': 777, 'message':', '.join(e.messages)})
        except Exception, e:
            # Rather than re-raising, we're going to things similar to
            # what Django does. The difference is returning a serialized
            # error message.
            return self._handle_500(request, e)

    return wrapper
```